# Link in ToolbarItem not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

im new on xamarin forms, i have managed to put in the app a menu toolbar this way:

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Test text"
                 Icon="add.png"
                 Priority="0"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked"
                 />
     </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

i want to take the user to another page that i have already created, however i have tried using this on the .cs file related, being ConstAvances the page where i want to redirect the user to:

```
  private async void MenuItem_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ConstAvances { Title = "Example title" });

    }
```

And nothing happens. on other sites of the app i have used a similar approach and it works. Am i missing something here? can someone please point me into the right direction?
thanks.

Comment: Can you see the toolbaritem? Can you press the item? The code seems to be correct.

Comment: yes i can see it and i can click on it however when i click nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have this in your code behind.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    // This is your toolbar's click event
    private void MenuItem_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Test", "Display alert", "OK");
    }
}
```